# How to expose my express app APIs to netlify serverless functions

Tags: reactjs, express, lambda, deployment, netlify

I have deployed my express app that serves reactjs index.html on netlify, I have searched the docs but couldn't find a solution, my api endpoints start with /api

```
 const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const connectDB = require("./db/connect");
const mainRouter = require("./routes");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
require("dotenv").config();
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      "https://master--sparkly-rugelach-ea7b04.netlify.app",
      "https://master--zingy-alfajores-1852f6.netlify.app/",
      "http://localhost:5173",
      "http://localhost:4173",
      "http://localhost:3001",
    ],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: null,
      secure: true, 
      sameSite: "none", 
    },
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session());

require("./middleware/passport-setup");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("./public"));
app.use("/api", mainRouter);
// app.use(errors());

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"));
});

const port = 3001;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);
    app.listen(port, console.log(`Listening on ${port}`));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

start();
```

the code above is my app.js

I also added a _redirects file in the root directory

> /api/*  /api/:splat  200

and added netlify.toml

```
    [functions]
  external_node_modules = ["express"]
  node_bundler = "esbuild"
[[redirects]]
  force = true
  from = "/api/*"
  status = 200
  to = "/.netlify/functions/api/:splat"
```

and netlify/functions/api.ts

```
const serverless = require('serverless-http')
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const api = express();

// const router = Router();
router.get('/hello', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

api.use('/api/', router);

export const handler = serverless(api);
```

And still it doesn't recognize the express app apis